# when we should use 'natural join', 'left outer join' and other joins in mysql?

Tags: mysql

when we should use 'natural join', 'left outer join' and other joins in mysql?

```
SELECT abc JOIN/INNER JOIN/ ???
```

Now I want to know difference between all these joins and when should we use which one ?

Comment: Why are you asking us?

Comment: Use Google and you will find it out

Answer (score -1):

see https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

I don't think there is a difference between JOIN and INNER JOIN.